# Is N--O--N known to exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, stability

Commonly, the empirical formula $\ce{N2O}$ refers to the molecule with structure $\ce{N\bond{~--}N\bond{~-}O}$.  Is the isomer $\ce{N-O-N}$ known to exist? I'm guessing it is significantly less stable than the NNO isomer, but that doesn't mean it's completely unknown.

Comment: What's your definition of existing? For that, being in minimum on PES would be already something. It's existence is fleeting, at best.

Comment: I don't know what PES is, but I'd take any one paper claiming to have synthesized and characterized it as a good start on evidence.

Comment: @zwol PES is a [potential energy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy_surface).

Comment: That you won't get. "synthesized and characterized" are wrong words. It's rather detect and that's optimistic.

Comment: Synthesized and characterized are the things that it was not.

Comment: Unfortunately N-O-N does not exist. At least, it has never been observed or synthesized. Maybe in some future ?

Comment: @Maurice Can you write an answer explaining how you know that?

Comment: The nitrogen atom never makes stable ions or molecules with only one covalent bond. N-H or N-Cl or N-OH do not exist. In this situation, N would have been surrounded by six electrons, and would not look like a noble gas. It would not be stable.

Comment: @Maurice Your last comment may be a useful "lie for children", but again isn't really correct. Such molecules may be very reactive, but may be present in interstellar space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidogen

Comment: See this papers where cyclic and linear NON isomers of N2O are calculated: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11209870/ ... https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225137278_Valence_bond_and_molecular_orbital_studies_of_three_N2O_isomers_and_valence_bond_representations_for_some_azide_decompositions